# How to search for exact match for non-word string in MS office word?

Tags: ms-word, vsto

for example, I have to search for "2/2" and I get these results:

**2/2**  good result

11/**2/2**022 bad result

when I use Advance search in MS -word the "find the whole word" is disabled because my search contains special characters.
also, I tried wildcard search but I didn't know how to construct a good search string for that
is there a way to find an exact match for non-word search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *wildcards*, with:

.Text = "<2/2>"

With this expression, the < and > specify a word start & end, respectively.

Event that, however, is prone to false matches with strings like 2/2/2022, since the / after the 2/2 designates a word end. Clearly, your code would need some additional checking to check whether a given match is valid. Such checking might be done via a Find expression like:

.Text = "[!/0-9A-Za-z]2/2[!/0-9A-Za-z]"

This tells Word to find 2/2 only when the preceding and following characters are not a /, a number, or a letter. Then, to manipulate the found text, you'd simply move the start of the found range forward one character and the end of the found range back one character.

Comment: I guess I'll check if there is  sounding white spaces and    if the selection length equal to my search string length

Comment: But the preceding/following characters might not be spaces; either might be a punctuation mark or paragraph/line break.

Comment: Yes that will be complex checking, and I'm not sure if i can use regex with find method

Comment: See latest addition to my answer.

Comment: Yes it's working thanks 
Just one more thing it not detecting the 2/2 if it is in the end of paragraph or the beginning.

Comment: It works for me unless it's the very first thing in the document. You could even deal with that by inserting a temporary paragraph break at the start of the document before doing the search.